# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime, asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, scriptmanager

,Hi,

I have a asp.net and c# website.

In the asp code I use

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

when I run my project I get this error:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

I am not using any dataTime things, on my site.

Then when I do refresh to the page the error disappears.

Stack Trace:

```
 [FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.]
   System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles) +3610514
   System.Windows.Forms.TypeLibraryTimeStampAttribute..ctor(String timestamp) +49
   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute._CreateCaObject(RuntimeModule pModule, IRuntimeMethodInfo pCtor, Byte** ppBlob, Byte* pEndBlob, Int32* pcNamedArgs) +0
   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.CreateCaObject(RuntimeModule module, IRuntimeMethodInfo ctor, IntPtr& blob, IntPtr blobEnd, Int32& namedArgs) +46
   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent) +529
   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeAssembly assembly, RuntimeType caType) +103
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetCustomAttributes(Boolean inherit) +33
   System.Web.UI.AssemblyCache.GetAjaxFrameworkAssemblyAttribute(Assembly assembly) +76
   System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.get_DefaultAjaxFrameworkAssembly() +388
   System.Web.UI.ScriptManager..ctor() +26
   ASP.newpipe_aspx.__BuildControlScriptManager1() in c:\Documents and Settings\Berzon\Desktop\Kinor\kWebGUI\NewPipe.aspx:17
   ASP.newpipe_aspx.__BuildControlBodyContent(Control __ctrl) in c:\Documents and Settings\Berzon\Desktop\Kinor\kWebGUI\NewPipe.aspx:16
   System.Web.UI.CompiledTemplateBuilder.InstantiateIn(Control container) +12
   System.Web.UI.MasterPage.InstantiateInContentPlaceHolder(Control contentPlaceHolder, ITemplate template) +87
   ASP.site_master.__BuildControlMainContent() in c:\Documents and Settings\Berzon\Desktop\Kinor\kWebGUI\Site.master:55
   ASP.site_master.__BuildControlfullPage() in c:\Documents and Settings\Berzon\Desktop\Kinor\kWebGUI\Site.master:16
   ASP.site_master.__BuildControlBody1() in c:\Documents and Settings\Berzon\Desktop\Kinor\kWebGUI\Site.master:15
   ASP.site_master.__BuildControlTree(site_master __ctrl) in c:\Documents and Settings\Berzon\Desktop\Kinor\kWebGUI\Site.master:1
   ASP.site_master.FrameworkInitialize() in c:\Documents and Settings\Berzon\Desktop\Kinor\kWebGUI\Site.master.cs:912308
   System.Web.UI.UserControl.InitializeAsUserControlInternal() +35
   System.Web.UI.MasterPage.CreateMaster(TemplateControl owner, HttpContext context, VirtualPath masterPageFile, IDictionary contentTemplateCollection) +8893254
   System.Web.UI.Page.get_Master() +54
   System.Web.UI.Page.ApplyMasterPage() +15
   System.Web.UI.Page.PerformPreInit() +45
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +328
```

What can be the issue?

Comment: Do you use `DateTime.Parse(someString)`? If so, post this code, please.

Comment: @ DotNET Ninja, i dont use that any were...

Comment: What .NET frameworks you have installed on the web server?

Comment: You need to post more code...

Comment: @ William Niu, I dont know what code to post, i dont know were and why this happens... what code should i post?

Comment: Are you using third-party controls? If so, see if the problem goes away if you remove any/all calls to the third-party control(s). Also, if you are calling a database, you should check your sql to make sure you are not setting a date column with a value that is not a datetime type. - Since you are struggling with narrowing down where to look for your problem, I have a hunch that the bugger may be in a Master Page .. don't forget to look there.

Comment: Does this [answer][1] help at all?  Seems to be a similar stack trace.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3783383/ajaxcontroltoolkit-datetime-formatexception

Comment: @Ovi the code that causes these lines in the stack dump `ASP.newpipe_aspx.__BuildControlScriptManager1() in c:\Documents and Settings\Berzon\Desktop\Kinor\kWebGUI\NewPipe.aspx:17
   ASP.newpipe_aspx.__BuildControlBodyContent(Control __ctrl) in c:\Documents and Settings\Berzon\Desktop\Kinor\kWebGUI\NewPipe.aspx:16` and include the code behind.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're referencing a library with a `[TypeLibraryTimeStampAttribute]` that has an invalid date passed to it.

Find that library and fix or remove it.

In general, it is a bad idea to use WinForms libraries in ASP.Net.

Answer (score 0):

remove all AxInterop.*.dll files from bin folder of web application